# VBA Multiline String Issues

Tags: string, vba

I am not having much experience writing VBA script, I am almost lost to find out in the multiline string. Where exactly I am lost is when I try to split the String in multiple lines, could you help me how to end

Working String is below before split:

```
strSQL = "insert into ded_limit_analysis (PDPD_ID,PDDS_DESC,PRODUCT_CAT,BASE_PDPD_ID,PROD_CYCLE,HMO_IND_DED) " & vbCrLf & _
 "values (" & "'" & Me.txt_pdpd_id & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_pdds & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.cbx_prod_type & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_base_pdpd & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.cbx_prod_cycle & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_hmo_ind_ded & "'" & ")"
```

The one not working is below, I am trying to split the lines because I have many columns to include in insert and it is more than 1000 caracters and not able to fit in single line (below is just sample, actual is much longer and I am forced to split the lines).

```
strSQL = "insert into ded_limit_analysis (PDPD_ID,PDDS_DESC,PRODUCT_CAT,BASE_PDPD_ID,PROD_CYCLE,HMO_IND_DED) " & vbCrLf & _
 "values (" & "'" & Me.txt_pdpd_id & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_pdds & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.cbx_prod_type & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_base_pdpd & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.cbx_prod_cycle & "'" & "," & " & vbCrLf &" _
 & "'" & Me.txt_hmo_ind_ded & "'" & ")"
```

Please advice where I am messing up, thanks

Answer (score 12):

You need to start the next line with "&"

So:

```
strSQL = "insert into ded_limit_analysis (PDPD_ID,PDDS_DESC,PRODUCT_CAT,BASE_PDPD_ID,PROD_CYCLE,HMO_IND_DED) " _
  & vbCrLf & "values (" & "'" & Me.txt_pdpd_id & "'" & "," _
  & "'" & Me.txt_pdds & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.cbx_prod_type _
  & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_base_pdpd & "'" & "," & "'" _
  & Me.cbx_prod_cycle & "'" & "," & vbCrLf _
  & "'" & Me.txt_hmo_ind_ded & "'" & ")"
```

Although, looking at the string, you can eliminate a lot of the "&" in your code.  This would be cleaner:

```
strSQL = "insert into ded_limit_analysis (PDPD_ID, " _
                                       & "PDDS_DESC, " _
                                       & "PRODUCT_CAT, " _
                                       & "BASE_PDPD_ID, " _
                                       & "PROD_CYCLE, " _
                                       & "HMO_IND_DED) " _
      & " values ('" & Me.txt_pdpd_id & "', '" _
                     & Me.txt_pdds & "', '"  _
                     & Me.cbx_prod_type & "', '" _
                     & Me.txt_base_pdpd & "', '"  _
                     & Me.cbx_prod_cycle & "', '" _
                     & Me.txt_hmo_ind_ded & "')"
```

It's just much easier to understand this way.  Also, you don't need "vbCrLf" in your SQL.  It's just white space.

Comment: your penultimate line in the first block has a trailing &. 2nd example looks a great improvement on OP code

Comment: I agree with simplifying the strings and trying to align wherever possible. My personal preference is to chop the lines to fit within the width of my code window. This aids debugging speed because you don't need to keep scrolling to the right (then left) to see what you have.

Comment: 2x edit because that first SQL portion was cluttered (to my eyes) :)

Answer (score 0):

On the second string `vbCrLf` is within quotes and is seen as a string rather than a command.

Try this code in place of the problem line above:

```
strSQL = "insert into ded_limit_analysis (PDPD_ID,PDDS_DESC,PRODUCT_CAT,BASE_PDPD_ID,PROD_CYCLE,HMO_IND_DED) " & vbCrLf & _
 "values (" & "'" & Me.txt_pdpd_id & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_pdds & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.cbx_prod_type & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_base_pdpd & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.cbx_prod_cycle & "'" & "," & vbCrLf _
 & "'" & Me.txt_hmo_ind_ded & "'" & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this option after seraching other post and works, thanks for proving other solutions, appreciate that.

```
 strSQL = "insert into ded_limit_analysis (PDPD_ID,PDDS_DESC,PRODUCT_CAT,BASE_PDPD_ID,PROD_CYCLE,HMO_IND_DED) " & vbCrLf & _
 "values (" & "'" & Me.txt_pdpd_id & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_pdds & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.cbx_prod_type & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.txt_base_pdpd & "'" & "," & "'" & Me.cbx_prod_cycle & "'" & ","
 strSQL = strSQL & "'" & Me.txt_hmo_ind_ded & "'" & ")"
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, but I suggest keeping your VBA clean with my code (above).  It's much easier to maintain and modify when it looks clean.